# Excel 2007 - cannot open the clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, clipboard

Every now and then within Excel when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> (cut) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (copy) I get the pop-up message 'Cannot open the Clipboard'.

I can't see any particular pattern to it but it's very annoying when it happens.

It doesn't happen in any other software I have installed.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Same here - very annoying. But probably off topic for SO.

Comment: Check [this thread](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/cannon-open-the-clipboard-error-in-excel-626596.html) - the last answer might work.

Comment: thanks for the replies alas i have none of the services in the last answer!?  Which is the best forum to post this sort of thing?

Comment: Probably superuser. I have voted to migrate your question there.

Comment: Ah ok - thank you, yes i have used superuser before

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed?

Comment: Yes i have ASAP Utilities installed.  Don't really want to uninstall it though.

Comment: I have a complex macro that encounters this from time to time.  I found that closing other office programs prevented the error from occurring as often.  It is strange, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Found possible solution on [MS answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-2007-cannot-open-clipboard/272c60f4-87d6-44d5-a04b-c83e9a59c84f?db=5&auth=1):

1. Try Excel in Safe Mode:
   *Start* - *All Programs* - *Accessories* - *Run*, type `Excel /safe`
2. If everything is OK in Safe Mode - try disabling Add-ins:
   a. *Office Icon* - *Excel Options*
   b. In the left hand side of the *Excel Options* dialog box, click *Add-Ins*
   c. Under *Manage* Click the *COM Add-ins*
   d. Uncheck all the Add-Ins listed under COM Add-ins
   e. Click close and restart Excel